# testing jsf spring application ajax request using jmeter

Tags: ajax, jsf, jmeter

I am using j meter in order to check how much time it takes from a push on an a4j button on the client side to the server's answer.

In order to achieve that I opened an HTTP request using fiddler and looked for:

1. ajax request decoded it and inserted it to the values in the http  header?
2. what else should i insert in order to send a request ? sessionID ? how to insert it to the http header?

I run it on the same machine where I run Tomcat and I can see in my Eclipse logger I enter to the right page but the button pushing is not pushed, can someone help me please.

This is the logger I am getting in Eclipse:

```
2011-08-17 09:52:32,673 ERROR [_ErrorPageWriter] An exception occurred
javax.faces.FacesException: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.StateUtils.symmetric(StateUtils.java:456)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.StateUtils.symmetric(StateUtils.java:494)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.StateUtils.decrypt(StateUtils.java:294)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.StateUtils.reconstruct(StateUtils.java:243)
    at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlResponseStateManager.getSavedState(HtmlResponseStateManager.java:187)
    at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlResponseStateManager.getTreeStructureToRestore(HtmlResponseStateManager.java:151)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateManager.restoreLogicalViewId(AjaxStateManager.java:564)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateManager.restoreStateFromSession(AjaxStateManager.java:495)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateManager.restoreView(AjaxStateManager.java:444)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.jsp.JspViewHandlerImpl.restoreView(JspViewHandlerImpl.java:515)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:107)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:85)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:103)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:76)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:151)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.MyFacesServlet.service(MyFacesServlet.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.coral.project.web.context.ExecutionContextFilter.doFilter(ExecutionContextFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESCipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.StateUtils.symmetric(StateUtils.java:452)
    ... 40 more
```

EDIT : I think this might be helpful to undersand my problem:

[image]

Comment: did you try my suggestion?  If so what result did you get?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not sure what your AJAX call requires to be successful, the easiest thing to do is use HTTP Proxy and record the action.  This will give you all the parameters that are passed to the server, along with their values at record time.

Then, where appropriate, you make the parameter values dynamic (sessionID is a good example of this).

[How to record](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf):